# Defining functions inside of views

Tags: django, django-views

I am attempting to create a job board website and upon entering a zip code in a form, that zip code is passed to a `search_results` view (as `zip_code`). In this view, I need to:

1. Get the surrounding zip codes (with a certain mile radius)
2. Get objects in DB that match those zip codes.

I have step one complete and have not implemented step two yet (actual code not that important to question):

```
from uszipcode import Zipcode, SearchEngine
def search_results(request, zip_code):
    zip_codes = []
    search = SearchEngine(simple_zipcode=True) # create SearchEngine object
    zip_code = search.by_zipcode(zip_code) #create Zipcode object?
    latitude = zip_code.lat
    longitude = zip_code.lng
    result = search.by_coordinates(latitude, longitude, radius = 5, returns = 5)
    for item in result:
        zip_codes.append(item.zipcode)

   # code that will return matching objects
```

My question is can you define functions inside of a view in Django, like such:

```
def search_results(request, zip_code):
  zip_codes = getSurroundingZipCodes(zip_code)
  results = getJobsInArea(zip_codes)
  return render(request, 'results.html', {'results: results})

  def getSurroundingZipCodes(zip_code):
      # logic for this function

  def getJobsInArea(zip_codes):
      # logic for this function
```

This is something I haven't seen in any tutorials so I feel like the answer is no, but I'm not sure why?

Comment: Might be cleaner to just define them outside your view as a function definition. Just call it from your view.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it. django view here is a function . You can define functions inside function.
That is how decorators work in python. But
why cant we define functions in seperate modules and import them above? Like in a file do

**utils.py**

```
def getSurroundingZipCodes(zip_code):
      # logic for this function

def getJobsInArea(zip_codes):
      # logic for this function
```

and simply import

`from utils import getSurroundingZipCodes,getJobsInArea`
 this way they will be resuable